# Is there any reason to keep starred items?

Tags: stardew-valley

Some crops and foraged items (and likely other classes of items) sometimes come with a silver or gold star next to them. Is there any reason to specifically hold onto these items?

Comment: I am aware of the need for at least gold starred items for the Community Center so that should be included in an answer but I am not sure if there are other reasons on top of that.

Comment: These items occasionally make for great gifts if you're trying to boost someone's social rating with you.

Comment: Food items with stars heal more health and energy if that counts.

Comment: @JonahBishop: Any refference for that? Since I read here from others that the decompiled code just diferentiates between how much a person likes something, not the quality.

Comment: It was mostly just an assumption. I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) As stated in a comment, there is a community centre package that requires Gold star crops. (Parsnips/Melons/Pumpkins/Corn, 5 of each)

2) In Fall, there is a festival where you will be able to show off some quality products and gain points based on their quality, so bringing higher quality items will net your more points.

3) Other than that, higher quality food will yield higher health/energy benefits.

4) I am unsure whether a higher quality items makes a "better" gift than the same item but with a lower quality, but that would be another reason to keep some good quality items.

I mostly sell the quality stuff myself and try and keep some good ones for the Fall festival.

Comment: @1: Something I missed early in the game, the bundle has only two slots to fill, so if you failed to get 5 gold Parsnips in Spring you can still go for, say, 5 Pumpkins and 5 Corn. Use fertilizer to get better crops!

Comment: ^ three slots*, but since you have 4 options you can indeed miss one safely.

Comment: Now I wonder if it was changed by any chance, because I very strongly remember double checking that there were indeed only 2 slots to fill.

Comment: Higher quality items do produce better gifts for people - http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Friendship#Gifts - Normal +0%, Silver Quality +10%, Gold Quality +25%, Iridium Quality +50%

Answer (score 3):

As well as the other benefits mentioned, the effect of any gift is multiplied by a factor of 10% for a silver-quality gift, 25% for a gold one and 50% for an iridium (not sure if this holds for disliked/hated gifts, but I assume it does).

So after giving someone a gift they love on a normal day (ie. not their birthday or anything), you'd normally get 80 friendship points, but if it had a gold star, for example, you'd get a total of (125% x 80), or 100 friendship points - that's 2/5 of a heart.